# Using keyboard specific keyboard-layouts in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I use a Kinesis Advantage with my MacBook Pro. While I use the dvorak layout when using the MBP's built-in keyboard the Kinesis has its own internal dvorak mode which assumes the host computer is using QWERTY.

Is it possible to have OS X change the keyboard layout depending on which keyboard is currently being used? As far as I am aware this is possible on linux systems with HAL support but I haven't been able to find any support docs for OSX that advertise this ability.

Thanks!

Comment: The type of keyboard being used is not normally sent by the keyboard.  My understanding of at least the basic keyboard buffer is there are only 3 signals sent by the keyboard.  Button Press, Which Button Was Pressed, and Button Release ( the same signal as Button Press ).  Its been 4 years since I wrote my keyboard buffer so my knowlege might be a little rusty.

Comment: I don't think so. But to make it more convenient you can assign keyboard shortcuts for switching the keyboard layout in: `Systen Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts` (I use cmd+arrow)